# Creating Amber/CHARMM style force field potential for energetic materials using DFT

Tags: density-functional-theory, molecular-dynamics, forcefields, charmm, amber

What are the basic steps and methodologies used in creating inter-atomic force field potential for CHARMM/Amber style for energetic materials with the help of DFT? What are the best possible free tools available for the task?

Comment: Take a look at this previous answer: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/8707/24

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if you can update us? Did the answer by Camps help you solve your problem? Have you figured out the answer elsewhere? Are you still working on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameterize a complex that contains Transition metal (Build Force Field)?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8706/parameterize-a-complex-that-contains-transition-metal-build-force-field)